# Hand rectangle detection with OpenPose

Tags: computer-vision, openpose

I'm using openpose, and I have no clue of how to start this task.

I need to draw a rectangle over the people's hand (not the pose of the fingers, just the rectangle), using the skeleton estimation that open pose provides, but I don't really have experience with this framework, and I'm having a hard time understanding the openpose code, so I don't know if somebody could give any advice or clue about how to achieve this task, might be with the right direction I could get it done.

Any comment is welcome, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to start at first, you should read more from the dlib home page before starting. After that you could follow my below suggestion to achieve your desire.

1. Download the source code from github [Dlib on github](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose)
2. Implement by the function `void work(TDatums& tDatums)` in the file /include/openpose/pose/wPoseExtractor.hpp
3. Get the keypoints and image as below code

> auto &ProceedData = (*tDatums)[0];
>
> Array keypoints = ProceedData.poseKeypoints;
>
> Mat proceedImage = ProceedData.cvOutputData;

4. You can draw your own image.